# Error linking OpenCV gpu::Stereo sample

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv

I'm trying to compile the `opencv-3.0.0-beta/samples/gpu/stereo_match.cpp` but I'm running into some linking errors:

```
/Users/George/Qt/5.7/clang_64/bin/qmake -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ../qt-test/qt-test.pro
/Applications/IDEsAndEditors/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -stdlib=libc++ -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/IDEsAndEditors/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wl,-rpath,/Users/George/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib -o qt-test.app/Contents/MacOS/qt-test main.o mainwindow.o camviewer.o moc_mainwindow.o   -F/Users/George/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lippicv -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_cudev -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(int)", referenced from:
      App::App(Params const&) in main.o
  "cv::cuda::GpuMat::defaultAllocator()", referenced from:
      App::run() in main.o
      App::App(Params const&) in main.o
  "cv::cuda::GpuMat::create(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat(cv::Size_<int>, int, cv::cuda::GpuMat::Allocator*) in main.o
  "cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload(cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      App::run() in main.o
      App::handleKey(char) in main.o
  "cv::cuda::GpuMat::release()", referenced from:
      cv::cuda::GpuMat::~GpuMat() in main.o
  "cv::cuda::getDevice()", referenced from:
      App::App(Params const&) in main.o
  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::String::~String() in main.o
  "cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      cv::String::String(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
      cv::String::String(char const*) in main.o
  "cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      App::run() in main.o
      App::handleKey(char) in main.o
  "cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::String const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)", referenced from:
      App::run() in main.o
  "cv::cuda::GpuMat::download(cv::_OutputArray const&) const", referenced from:
      App::run() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [qt-test.app/Contents/MacOS/qt-test] Error 1
22:12:45: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qt-test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

I'm using Qt Creator 4.0.2 and the project file from this article [Configuring Qt for OpenCV on OSX](http://www.learnopencv.com/configuring-qt-for-opencv-on-osx/). I've installed OpenCV 3.0 via homebrew according to the guide:

```
  Built from source on 2016-06-24 at 23:14:16 with: --with-contrib --with-cuda --with-openni2
```

I've double checked and cuda libraries seem to be installed:

```
libopencv_aruco.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_cudafilters.3.1.0.dylib   libopencv_dnn.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_imgproc.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_saliency.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_video.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_aruco.3.1.dylib       libopencv_cudafilters.3.1.dylib     libopencv_dnn.3.1.dylib         libopencv_imgproc.3.1.dylib     libopencv_saliency.3.1.dylib        libopencv_video.3.1.dylib
libopencv_aruco.dylib           libopencv_cudafilters.dylib     libopencv_dnn.dylib         libopencv_imgproc.dylib         libopencv_saliency.dylib        libopencv_video.dylib
libopencv_bgsegm.3.1.0.dylib        libopencv_cudaimgproc.3.1.0.dylib   libopencv_dpm.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_line_descriptor.3.1.0.dylib   libopencv_shape.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_videoio.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_bgsegm.3.1.dylib      libopencv_cudaimgproc.3.1.dylib     libopencv_dpm.3.1.dylib         libopencv_line_descriptor.3.1.dylib libopencv_shape.3.1.dylib       libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib
libopencv_bgsegm.dylib          libopencv_cudaimgproc.dylib     libopencv_dpm.dylib         libopencv_line_descriptor.dylib     libopencv_shape.dylib           libopencv_videoio.dylib
libopencv_bioinspired.3.1.0.dylib   libopencv_cudalegacy.3.1.0.dylib    libopencv_face.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_ml.3.1.0.dylib        libopencv_stereo.3.1.0.dylib        libopencv_videostab.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_bioinspired.3.1.dylib     libopencv_cudalegacy.3.1.dylib      libopencv_face.3.1.dylib        libopencv_ml.3.1.dylib          libopencv_stereo.3.1.dylib      libopencv_videostab.3.1.dylib
libopencv_bioinspired.dylib     libopencv_cudalegacy.dylib      libopencv_face.dylib            libopencv_ml.dylib          libopencv_stereo.dylib          libopencv_videostab.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_cudaobjdetect.3.1.0.dylib libopencv_features2d.3.1.0.dylib    libopencv_objdetect.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_stitching.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_xfeatures2d.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.3.1.dylib     libopencv_cudaobjdetect.3.1.dylib   libopencv_features2d.3.1.dylib      libopencv_objdetect.3.1.dylib       libopencv_stitching.3.1.dylib       libopencv_xfeatures2d.3.1.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.dylib         libopencv_cudaobjdetect.dylib       libopencv_features2d.dylib      libopencv_objdetect.dylib       libopencv_stitching.dylib       libopencv_xfeatures2d.dylib
libopencv_ccalib.3.1.0.dylib        libopencv_cudaoptflow.3.1.0.dylib   libopencv_flann.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_optflow.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_structured_light.3.1.0.dylib  libopencv_ximgproc.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_ccalib.3.1.dylib      libopencv_cudaoptflow.3.1.dylib     libopencv_flann.3.1.dylib       libopencv_optflow.3.1.dylib     libopencv_structured_light.3.1.dylib    libopencv_ximgproc.3.1.dylib
libopencv_ccalib.dylib          libopencv_cudaoptflow.dylib     libopencv_flann.dylib           libopencv_optflow.dylib         libopencv_structured_light.dylib    libopencv_ximgproc.dylib
libopencv_core.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_cudastereo.3.1.0.dylib    libopencv_fuzzy.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_photo.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_superres.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_xobjdetect.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_core.3.1.dylib        libopencv_cudastereo.3.1.dylib      libopencv_fuzzy.3.1.dylib       libopencv_photo.3.1.dylib       libopencv_superres.3.1.dylib        libopencv_xobjdetect.3.1.dylib
libopencv_core.dylib            libopencv_cudastereo.dylib      libopencv_fuzzy.dylib           libopencv_photo.dylib           libopencv_superres.dylib        libopencv_xobjdetect.dylib
libopencv_cudaarithm.3.1.0.dylib    libopencv_cudawarping.3.1.0.dylib   libopencv_hdf.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_plot.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_surface_matching.3.1.0.dylib  libopencv_xphoto.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_cudaarithm.3.1.dylib      libopencv_cudawarping.3.1.dylib     libopencv_hdf.3.1.dylib         libopencv_plot.3.1.dylib        libopencv_surface_matching.3.1.dylib    libopencv_xphoto.3.1.dylib
libopencv_cudaarithm.dylib      libopencv_cudawarping.dylib     libopencv_hdf.dylib         libopencv_plot.dylib            libopencv_surface_matching.dylib    libopencv_xphoto.dylib
libopencv_cudabgsegm.3.1.0.dylib    libopencv_cudev.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_highgui.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_reg.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_text.3.1.0.dylib      pkgconfig
libopencv_cudabgsegm.3.1.dylib      libopencv_cudev.3.1.dylib       libopencv_highgui.3.1.dylib     libopencv_reg.3.1.dylib         libopencv_text.3.1.dylib        python2.7
libopencv_cudabgsegm.dylib      libopencv_cudev.dylib           libopencv_highgui.dylib         libopencv_reg.dylib         libopencv_text.dylib
libopencv_cudafeatures2d.3.1.0.dylib    libopencv_datasets.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_rgbd.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_tracking.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_cudafeatures2d.3.1.dylib  libopencv_datasets.3.1.dylib        libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.dylib       libopencv_rgbd.3.1.dylib        libopencv_tracking.3.1.dylib
libopencv_cudafeatures2d.dylib      libopencv_datasets.dylib        libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib       libopencv_rgbd.dylib            libopencv_tracking.dylib
```

The .pro file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qt-test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    camviewer.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    camviewer.h \
    tick_meter.hpp

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5


QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
CONFIG  += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

So as far as I can tell I've got opencv 3.0 installed with CUDA and I'm linking against the libraries, but I'm not sure why those symbols seem to be missing.

How can I double checked I'm linking correctly ?

What's the correct way to link and compile this sample ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/cudastereo.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

bool help_showed = false;

struct Params
{
    Params();
    static Params read(int argc, char** argv);

    string left;
    string right;

    string method_str() const
    {
        switch (method)
        {
        case BM: return "BM";
        case BP: return "BP";
        case CSBP: return "CSBP";
        }
        return "";
    }
    enum {BM, BP, CSBP} method;
    int ndisp; // Max disparity + 1
};


struct App
{
    App(const Params& p);
    void run();
    void handleKey(char key);
    void printParams() const;

    void workBegin() { work_begin = getTickCount(); }
    void workEnd()
    {
        int64 d = getTickCount() - work_begin;
        double f = getTickFrequency();
        work_fps = f / d;
    }

    string text() const
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "(" << p.method_str() << ") FPS: " << setiosflags(ios::left)
            << setprecision(4) << work_fps;
        return ss.str();
    }
private:
    Params p;
    bool running;

    Mat left_src, right_src;
    Mat left, right;
    cuda::GpuMat d_left, d_right;

    Ptr<cuda::StereoBM> bm;
    Ptr<cuda::StereoBeliefPropagation> bp;
    Ptr<cuda::StereoConstantSpaceBP> csbp;

    int64 work_begin;
    double work_fps;
};

static void printHelp()
{
    cout << "Usage: stereo_match_gpu\n"
        << "\t--left <left_view> --right <right_view> # must be rectified\n"
        << "\t--method <stereo_match_method> # BM | BP | CSBP\n"
        << "\t--ndisp <number> # number of disparity levels\n";
    help_showed = true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            printHelp();
            return 1;
        }
        Params args = Params::read(argc, argv);
        if (help_showed)
            return -1;
        App app(args);
        app.run();
    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        cout << "error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


Params::Params()
{
    method = BM;
    ndisp = 64;
}


Params Params::read(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Params p;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (string(argv[i]) == "--left") p.left = argv[++i];
        else if (string(argv[i]) == "--right") p.right = argv[++i];
        else if (string(argv[i]) == "--method")
        {
            if (string(argv[i + 1]) == "BM") p.method = BM;
            else if (string(argv[i + 1]) == "BP") p.method = BP;
            else if (string(argv[i + 1]) == "CSBP") p.method = CSBP;
            else throw runtime_error("unknown stereo match method: " + string(argv[i + 1]));
            i++;
        }
        else if (string(argv[i]) == "--ndisp") p.ndisp = atoi(argv[++i]);
        else if (string(argv[i]) == "--help") printHelp();
        else throw runtime_error("unknown key: " + string(argv[i]));
    }

    return p;
}


App::App(const Params& params)
    : p(params), running(false)
{
    cv::cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(cv::cuda::getDevice());

    cout << "stereo_match_gpu sample\n";
    cout << "\nControls:\n"
        << "\tesc - exit\n"
        << "\tp - print current parameters\n"
        << "\tg - convert source images into gray\n"
        << "\tm - change stereo match method\n"
        << "\ts - change Sobel prefiltering flag (for BM only)\n"
        << "\t1/q - increase/decrease maximum disparity\n"
        << "\t2/w - increase/decrease window size (for BM only)\n"
        << "\t3/e - increase/decrease iteration count (for BP and CSBP only)\n"
        << "\t4/r - increase/decrease level count (for BP and CSBP only)\n";
}


void App::run()
{
    // Load images
    left_src = imread(p.left);
    right_src = imread(p.right);
    if (left_src.empty()) throw runtime_error("can't open file \"" + p.left + "\"");
    if (right_src.empty()) throw runtime_error("can't open file \"" + p.right + "\"");
    cvtColor(left_src, left, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(right_src, right, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    d_left.upload(left);
    d_right.upload(right);

    imshow("left", left);
    imshow("right", right);

    // Set common parameters
    bm = cuda::createStereoBM(p.ndisp);
    bp = cuda::createStereoBeliefPropagation(p.ndisp);
    csbp = cv::cuda::createStereoConstantSpaceBP(p.ndisp);

    // Prepare disparity map of specified type
    Mat disp(left.size(), CV_8U);
    cuda::GpuMat d_disp(left.size(), CV_8U);

    cout << endl;
    printParams();

    running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        workBegin();
        switch (p.method)
        {
        case Params::BM:
            if (d_left.channels() > 1 || d_right.channels() > 1)
            {
                cout << "BM doesn't support color images\n";
                cvtColor(left_src, left, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                cvtColor(right_src, right, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                cout << "image_channels: " << left.channels() << endl;
                d_left.upload(left);
                d_right.upload(right);
                imshow("left", left);
                imshow("right", right);
            }
            bm->compute(d_left, d_right, d_disp);
            break;
        case Params::BP: bp->compute(d_left, d_right, d_disp); break;
        case Params::CSBP: csbp->compute(d_left, d_right, d_disp); break;
        }
        workEnd();

        // Show results
        d_disp.download(disp);
        putText(disp, text(), Point(5, 25), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, Scalar::all(255));
        imshow("disparity", disp);

        handleKey((char)waitKey(3));
    }
}


void App::printParams() const
{
    cout << "--- Parameters ---\n";
    cout << "image_size: (" << left.cols << ", " << left.rows << ")\n";
    cout << "image_channels: " << left.channels() << endl;
    cout << "method: " << p.method_str() << endl
        << "ndisp: " << p.ndisp << endl;
    switch (p.method)
    {
    case Params::BM:
        cout << "win_size: " << bm->getBlockSize() << endl;
        cout << "prefilter_sobel: " << bm->getPreFilterType() << endl;
        break;
    case Params::BP:
        cout << "iter_count: " << bp->getNumIters() << endl;
        cout << "level_count: " << bp->getNumLevels() << endl;
        break;
    case Params::CSBP:
        cout << "iter_count: " << csbp->getNumIters() << endl;
        cout << "level_count: " << csbp->getNumLevels() << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void App::handleKey(char key)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 27:
        running = false;
        break;
    case 'p': case 'P':
        printParams();
        break;
    case 'g': case 'G':
        if (left.channels() == 1 && p.method != Params::BM)
        {
            left = left_src;
            right = right_src;
        }
        else
        {
            cvtColor(left_src, left, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            cvtColor(right_src, right, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        }
        d_left.upload(left);
        d_right.upload(right);
        cout << "image_channels: " << left.channels() << endl;
        imshow("left", left);
        imshow("right", right);
        break;
    case 'm': case 'M':
        switch (p.method)
        {
        case Params::BM:
            p.method = Params::BP;
            break;
        case Params::BP:
            p.method = Params::CSBP;
            break;
        case Params::CSBP:
            p.method = Params::BM;
            break;
        }
        cout << "method: " << p.method_str() << endl;
        break;
    case 's': case 'S':
        if (p.method == Params::BM)
        {
            switch (bm->getPreFilterType())
            {
            case 0:
                bm->setPreFilterType(cv::StereoBM::PREFILTER_XSOBEL);
                break;
            case cv::StereoBM::PREFILTER_XSOBEL:
                bm->setPreFilterType(0);
                break;
            }
            cout << "prefilter_sobel: " << bm->getPreFilterType() << endl;
        }
        break;
    case '1':
        p.ndisp = p.ndisp == 1 ? 8 : p.ndisp + 8;
        cout << "ndisp: " << p.ndisp << endl;
        bm->setNumDisparities(p.ndisp);
        bp->setNumDisparities(p.ndisp);
        csbp->setNumDisparities(p.ndisp);
        break;
    case 'q': case 'Q':
        p.ndisp = max(p.ndisp - 8, 1);
        cout << "ndisp: " << p.ndisp << endl;
        bm->setNumDisparities(p.ndisp);
        bp->setNumDisparities(p.ndisp);
        csbp->setNumDisparities(p.ndisp);
        break;
    case '2':
        if (p.method == Params::BM)
        {
            bm->setBlockSize(min(bm->getBlockSize() + 1, 51));
            cout << "win_size: " << bm->getBlockSize() << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 'w': case 'W':
        if (p.method == Params::BM)
        {
            bm->setBlockSize(max(bm->getBlockSize() - 1, 2));
            cout << "win_size: " << bm->getBlockSize() << endl;
        }
        break;
    case '3':
        if (p.method == Params::BP)
        {
            bp->setNumIters(bp->getNumIters() + 1);
            cout << "iter_count: " << bp->getNumIters() << endl;
        }
        else if (p.method == Params::CSBP)
        {
            csbp->setNumIters(csbp->getNumIters() + 1);
            cout << "iter_count: " << csbp->getNumIters() << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 'e': case 'E':
        if (p.method == Params::BP)
        {
            bp->setNumIters(max(bp->getNumIters() - 1, 1));
            cout << "iter_count: " << bp->getNumIters() << endl;
        }
        else if (p.method == Params::CSBP)
        {
            csbp->setNumIters(max(csbp->getNumIters() - 1, 1));
            cout << "iter_count: " << csbp->getNumIters() << endl;
        }
        break;
    case '4':
        if (p.method == Params::BP)
        {
            bp->setNumLevels(bp->getNumLevels() + 1);
            cout << "level_count: " << bp->getNumLevels() << endl;
        }
        else if (p.method == Params::CSBP)
        {
            csbp->setNumLevels(csbp->getNumLevels() + 1);
            cout << "level_count: " << csbp->getNumLevels() << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 'r': case 'R':
        if (p.method == Params::BP)
        {
            bp->setNumLevels(max(bp->getNumLevels() - 1, 1));
            cout << "level_count: " << bp->getNumLevels() << endl;
        }
        else if (p.method == Params::CSBP)
        {
            csbp->setNumLevels(max(csbp->getNumLevels() - 1, 1));
            cout << "level_count: " << csbp->getNumLevels() << endl;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

**Update**
Any hints on how to compile in Qt Creator as well ?

Comment: Not sure if it will solve the issue, but use the sample of opencv 3.1,and not 3.0 beta, since you installed opencv 3.1. You'll find it on github, just be sure the the branch/tag is 3.1. The api has changed from 3.0 beta...

Comment: @Miki Good hint, however, I've compared [stereo_match.cpp from opencv 3.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.0.0/samples/gpu/stereo_match.cpp) with [stereo_match.cpp from opencv 3.1](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.1.0/samples/gpu/stereo_match.cpp) and they are identical.

Comment: You could try explicitly linking with "-llibopencvxxx".... I usually do like this, but not on osx... just a wild guess ;D

Comment: I think Qt does that: ```-lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face```...

Comment: ```-lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lippicv -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_cudev -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL```

Comment: @Miki I think it finally clicked what you meant by *explicitly* ;)
Thank you for the advice, that worked! Any tips on how I could replicate in Qt ? (Guessing ```clang++``` has something to do with it ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Miki's tip (explicitly) I managed to compile the sample, but from command like only:

```
g++ stereo_match.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lippicv -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_cudev -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -o stereo_match
```

Most of the include and library flags were generated via `pkg-config`:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

I just needed to manually add this path:

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib
```

because of a previous error:

```
ld: library not found for -lippicv
```